# Better variable exploring when debugging C++ code with Eclipse/CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Using Eclipse and CDT to debug C++ code the variable windows is cumbersome and not very informative for types defined in the standard template library or in boost (e.g. shared_ptr).

Just an example how this may look like for an std::vector:

```
bar {…}
    std::_Vector_base<TSample<MyTraits>, std::allocator<TSample<MyTraits> > >   
        _M_impl {…} 
            std::allocator<TSample<MyTraits> >  {…} 
            _M_start    0x00007ffff7fb5010  
            _M_finish   0x00007ffff7fd4410  
            _M_end_of_storage   0x00007ffff7fd5010
```

Even if this information about the internals of those types may be useful, in almost any cases I would expect a clearer presentation here, i.e. a list of values for the std::vector. Are there any tools, plugins or other modifications around which can do this?

**EDIT**

The following solutions does not work for linux. I am using ubuntu 14.04, eclipse, g++, gdb.

I cant find a package gdb-python and linux does not use mingw

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need a version of GDB capable of using python to pretty print structures.  I know at least on windows using mingw that this is not provided in the default install.

Pretty Printers are python modules which tell gdb how to display a given structure.  You can write your own, but there are already printers for STL available for download.

To Get Pretty Printers working on Windows (instructions should be similiar for other OS's):

**Prerequisites**

- Make sure you have you have Python 2.7 installed and in the system path.

  > http://www.python.org/download/
- Make sure MinGW-get is installed

  > http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/
- Make sure you have an SVN client are installed

**Installation:**

- Open a command Shell and type:

  ```
  mingw-get install gdb-python
  ```
- When its finished cd to a local directory and install the printers by typing:

  ```
  svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python
  ```
- Open the .gdbinit (create it in a text editor if need be) and type the following replaceing "C:/directory" with the folder that you checked the printers into.

  > Python
  >   import sys
  >   sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/directory')
  >   from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
  >   register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
  >   end

**Eclipse Setup**

- Go To Windows > Preferences > C/C++ > Debug > GDB
- Where it Says GDB Debugger put the path to the python enabled GDB it will most likely be in the mingw /bin folder with a name like gdb-python27.exe
- Where it says GDB Command File put the path to the .gdb init file you made earlier.

That's it, debug like normal, the stl structures should be much easier to read.

Comment: Can you please give the solution for linux.... linux does not have mingw, and i cant find any package gdb-python.

Comment: After starting debugging I receive error message "Could not determine GDB version using command: gdb-python27.exe --version".

Comment: Problem solved by installing 32bit version of Python instead of 64bit.

Comment: When I do this, and try to debug, I get `Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-file-exec-and-symbols D:/Dropbox/eclipse/ProofTool/Debug/ProofTool.exe
Error message from debugger back end:
"D:\Dropbox\eclipse\ProofTool\Debug\ProofTool.exe": not in executable format: File format not recognized
"D:\Dropbox\eclipse\ProofTool\Debug\ProofTool.exe": not in executable format: File format not recognized`
To me, it appears, that this is also a 64/32 bit problem. I'm on Windows 7 64 bit, and I want to debug 64 bit programs. Only 32 bit python works, as @truthseeker mentioned

Comment: I am now pretty sure that I need a 64 bit version of GDB, but mingw-get only installs a 32 bit version. How to get a 64 bit CDB version (on Windows, which supports python)? I am stuck here with my question now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912471/how-to-install-gdb-with-python-support-on-windows-7

Comment: I found a solution. Using the MinGW distribution from http://equation.com (since I want current versions of the gcc compiler on Windows 7), there is the problem, that the gdb.exe of the equation.com distribution have not been configured using `--with-python`. Since also building GDB by myself using MSYS failed (`make` got stuck at `checking version of bison...`), I found a 64 bit MinGW distribution which contain GDB: "MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows" (from http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download) I installed it and linked Eclipse to gdb.exe of this outdated MinGW 64 bit version. It works.

Answer (score 21):

Well, gdb don't natively support STL containers. You can't say this is incorrect, since it will expose the inner workings of the STL objects, but most of the time it is not what we want, right?

If you're using gdb 7.0 you can take advantage of the pretty printers. This website http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport has a pretty simple tutorial on how to set them. I copied below the part that interests you:

> 1. Check-out the latest Python libstdc++ printers to a place on your
>      machine. In a local directory, do:
>
>    ```
>        svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python
>    ```
> 2. Add the following to your ~/.gdbinit. The path needs to match
>      where the python module above was
>      checked-out. So if checked out to:
>      /home/maude/gdb_printers/, the path
>      would be as written in the example:
>
>    ```
>        python
>        import sys
>        sys.path.insert(0, '/home/maude/gdb_printers/python')
>        from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
>        register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
>        end
>    ```
>
> The path should be the only element
>   that needs to be adjusted in the
>   example above. Once loaded, STL
>   classes that the printers support
>   should printed in a more
>   human-readable format. To print the
>   classes in the old style, use the /r
>   (raw) switch in the print command
>   (i.e., print /r foo). This will print
>   the classes as if the Python
>   pretty-printers were not loaded.

Since you're using eclipse cdt, don't forget to point your debug configuration to your .gdbinit file. When creating a new Debug Configuration, go to the Debugger tab and put the path to the .gdbinit file in the "GDB command file" field.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I followed the instructions and did set the correct paths, but it is not working. Any suggestions what might be wrong?

Comment: It wasn't working for me either in Linux. Solved it commenting out the lines
 
`from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers(gdb.current_objfile())`

in the libstdcxx/v6/__init__.py file.

Comment: Its working for me under Linux. However I had to set the path as /home/user/pathtoprettyprinters while ~/pathtoprettyprinters did not work! In eclipse I had to put the path to .gdbinit under window->preferences->C/C++->debug->gdb and then recreate my debug launching configuration to get it working. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985414/enable-pretty-printing-for-gdb-in-eclipse-cdt

Answer (score 10):

In debug view in variables list expand vector:

`"vector_name"` -> `std::_Vector_base<"datatype">` -> `_M_impl`

then right click on `_M_start` and select "Display as array...", type its length and then click OK. Now you can expand each item of your vector.

Comment: Make sure to expand `_M_start` after going through "Display as array...".

Comment: This is a brilliant answer. Don't know why this wasn't accepted.

Comment: This works for a `vector<T>` because it has an underlying member of type `T[]`. For other STL types this doesn't work. This is a good and simple solution for vectors and strings.

Answer (score 8):

If you have `gdb` support for `CDT` (see, for example, [GDB in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758794/how-do-i-use-gdb-in-eclipse-for-c-c-debugging)), you could try this: [De-referencing STL containers](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html#STLDEREFhttp://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html#STLDEREF)

Long ago I also stumbled upon your same problem. It was a pain to check the STL containers. Then I found that link and added to my `.gdbinit` file some of those definitions. Life was easier after that.

**NOTE:** My `gdb` version is 7.1 and adding those definitions work fine. I don't know if in newer versions of `gdb` they are already included.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to expand on the Windows 7 response because some key steps are left out:

## This is for MinGW users with Eclipse CDT

0) If you don't have python GDB, open a shell/command and use MinGW-get.exe to 'install' 
   Python-enabled GDB e.g.

```
   MinGw-get.exe install gdb-python
```

1a) Get Python 2.7.x from http://python.org/download/ and install

1b) Make sure PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME are set in your environment:

```
 PYTHONPATH should be C:\Python27\Lib   (or similar)
 PYTHONHOME should be C:\Python27
```

1c) Add PYTHONHOME to your PATH

```
 %PYTHONHOME%;...
```

2a) Open a text enter, enter the following statements. Notice the 3rd line is
    pointing to where the python scripts are located. See notes below about this!

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/MinGW/share/gcc-4.6.1/python')         
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

2b) Save as '.gdbinit' NOTE: Windows explorer will not let you name a file that starts with
    with a period from explorer. Most text edits (including Notepad) will let you. GDB init
    files are like 'scripts' of GDB commands that GBD will execute upon loading.

2c) The '.gdbinit' file needs to be in the working directory of GDB (most likely this is
    your projects root directory but your IDE can tell you.

3) Open your Eclipse (or other IDE) Preferences dialog. Go to the C++ Debugger sub-menu.

4) Configure Eclipse to use `C:\MinGW\bin\gdb-python27.exe` as the debugger and your `.gdbinit` as the config file.

5a) Re-create all your debug launch configurations (delete the old one and create a new one from scratch).

```
--OR--
```

5b) Edit each debug configuration and point it to the new gdb-python.exe AND point it to the.

### If you run into issues:

--Don't forget to change the location to the python directory in the above python code!
   This directory is created by MinGW, so don't go looking to download the pretty printers, MinGW
   did it for you in step zero. Just goto your MinGW install director, the share folder,
   the GCC folder (has version number) and you will find python folder. This location is what
   should be in python script loaded by GDB.

--Also, the .gdbinit is a PITA, make sure its named correctly and in the working folder of GDB 
   which isn't necessarily where gdb-python.exe is located! Look at your GDB output when loading GDB to see if   a) 'python-enabled' appears during load and that the statements in the .gdbinit  are appearing.

--Finally, I had alot of issues with the system variables. If python gives you 'ImportError' then most likely you have not set PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME.

--The directory with 'gdb-python27' (e.g. C:\MinGW\bin') should also be on your path and if it is, it makes setting up eclipse a bit nicer because you don't need to put in absolute paths. But still, sometimes the .gbdinit needs an absoulte path. if it works you'll see output from gbd (console->gdb traces) like this on startup of debugger:

```
835,059 4^done
835,059 (gdb) 
835,059 5-enable-pretty-printing
835,069 5^done
....
835,129 12^done
835,129 (gdb) 
835,129 13source C:\MinGW\bin\.gdbinit
835,139 &"source C:\\MinGW\\bin\\.gdbinit\n"
835,142 13^done
835,142 (gdb)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that JDT (Java environment in eclipse) provides custom "formatters" to be applied when displaying variable values in debug views. A quick look at google for the same in CDT brings this page:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/Better_Debugging_%28GSoC_project%29

I don't know if this has been yet integrated in the main CDT line, may be you can try to right click on a variable while debugging (in the last CDT) and see if there is a custom formater entry. If not available I recomend you to add a new tracker entry in CDT tracker to ask this enhancement.