# Debug LLVM using Eclipse

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt, llvm

I am working on LLVM. While debugging it using Eclipse, I came across certain data structures whose contents I want to see. But while debugging, Eclipse only gives me the address of that particular data structure and not its contents.

E.g. While viewing contents of SmallVectorImpl &Ops, it gives something like this

```
Name :  Ops
    Details:@0xbfffef94
    Default:{...}
    Decimal:{...}
    Hex:{...}
    Binary:{...}
    Octal:{...}
```

Please tell me if there is any plugin available to view the contents of these data structures.

Comment: What flags were used in application build? Try to add '-g' flag.

Comment: Is the structure SmallVectorImpl part of a given implementation of the C++ standard library ?

Comment: SmallVector is class defined by llvm.

Comment: I'm not sure but if SmallVector is a entry of a static table, you can't see its content. if the designer use this approach to implement some kind of reference counting data structure.

Comment: I encountered the same issue and still don't know how to resolve it...

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to the issue presented here (also, just seen this is massive thread necro, sorry):

[How to enable gdb pretty printing for C++ STL objects in Eclipse CDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985414/enable-pretty-printing-for-gdb-in-eclipse-cdt)

Of course, you'll need to change the linked pretty printing script, but it's a start.