# What's the file .gdbinit meant for?

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, emacs, gdb

Sorry for my ignorance but I saw there were a lot questions about `.gdbinit` file. I just cannot understand what this file brings to me. Seems that it is used for some python script for modern gdb, making the output of gdb more readable.

But what's the *exact* difference? How can I utilize this file in debugging environment such as Emacs/eclipse CDT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explained here: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/gdbinit-man.html

This is typically used to connect to remote target, configure memory types, etc.

Comment: You can write any required gdb commands to this file. And you can use conditions, loops, etc. You could for example put something like "target remote blah.blah.com:1234", "mem 0 0x100000 ro" to connect to remote system...

Comment: But I saw one of the .gdbinit files containing some words like `python ... from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers ...`, and without this, gdb would emit a warning(something about not finding needed ) at the startup(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985414/enable-pretty-printing-for-gdb-in-eclipse-cdt). Then what's that supposed to be?

Comment: BTW, is there any example/tutorial for this?

Comment: Most of Debugging with gdb (http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) applies.

Answer (score 1):

Look for  ["Next explains usage while debugging in Eclipse"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985414/enable-pretty-printing-for-gdb-in-eclipse-cdt) to see how to install and configure .gdbinit file in eclipse.

.gdbinit allows running specific commands which comes in existing once gdb is executed.  For example: Following command once specified in .gdbinit which will show assembly in Intel format.

```
set disassembly-flavor intel
```

Also gdb macros can be defined as per custom needed.

[Here is sample .gdbinit.](http://www.dirac.org/linux/gdb/03-Initialization,_Listing,_And_Running.php)