# Eclipse CDT Kepler does not allow "Display as array..."

Tags: c++, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to debug a C++ program using Eclipse CDT:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> test (4,100);
  return 0;
}
```

If I place a breakpoint to debug, and I click "Display as Array..." for my vector variable I get the following error:

```
(*((test)+0)@4) Error: Multiple errors reported.\ Failed to execute MI command: -var-create - * (*((test)+0)@4) Error message from debugger back end: No symbol "operator+" in current context.\ Unable to create variable object
```

How can I view the values of my arrays while debugging?

I am using:

- Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler)
- Ubuntu 13 64-bit
- gcc 4.7.3 (compiled with `-g3` and `-O0`)
- gdb 7.5.91
- GDB (DSF) Create Process Launcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dive a bit deeper into the structure of the `std::vector` variable, and look for s.th. named `_M_start` or alike (may be implementation dependent).
Cast this one to the final type array you know and want to see.

The reason is, that `std::vector<T>` just wraps and manages an array of `T` internally and thus can't be displayed as an array itself.

Comment: This works but it's not pretty. Can't eclipse do something internally to figure that out and display the information as one would expect in a more user-friendly fashion?

Comment: @NealKruis Send as a feature request or [participate](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse can, see the snapshot and the instructions [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_can_I_inspect_the_contents_of_STL_containers.3F) and [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985414/enable-pretty-printing-for-gdb-in-eclipse-cdt) post helped me out as well.