# How do I apply the printers.py modification? (Linux OS)

Tags: python, c++, linux, gdb

I checked the core file because the process(c++ lang) running on Linux died, and the contents of the core file

[Corefile]

```
File "/usr/lib64/../share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 558, in to_string

return self.val['_M_dataplus']['_M_p'].lazy_string (length = len)

RuntimeError: Cannot access memory at address 0x3b444e45203b290f
```

I think that there was a problem with class StdStringPrinter at printers.py.
So I looked up a text that explained the problem I was looking for on this site  , modified printers.py, and created a .gdbinit on my home path and wrote the content.

[How to enable gdb pretty printing for C++ STL objects in Eclipse CDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985414/how-to-enable-gdb-pretty-printing-for-c-stl-objects-in-eclipse-cdt)

[Eclipse/CDT Pretty Print Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837549/eclipse-cdt-pretty-print-errors)

But this method is a little different from the one I'm looking for because it's done in Eclipse.

my gdb version is 7.6.1-94.el7

[printer.py]

```
class StdStringPrinter:
"Print a std::basic_string of some kind"

def __init__(self, typename, val):
    self.val = val

def to_string(self):
    # Make sure &string works, too.
    type = self.val.type
    if type.code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_REF:
        type = type.target ()

    sys.stdout.write("HelloWorld")  // TEST Code
    # Calculate the length of the string so that to_string returns
    # the string according to length, not according to first null
    # encountered.
    ptr = self.val ['_M_dataplus']['_M_p']
    realtype = type.unqualified ().strip_typedefs ()
    reptype = gdb.lookup_type (str (realtype) + '::_Rep').pointer ()
    header = ptr.cast(reptype) - 1
    len = header.dereference ()['_M_length']
    if hasattr(ptr, "lazy_string"):
        return ptr.lazy_string (length = len)
    return ptr.string (length = len)

def display_hint (self):
    return 'string'
```

[.gdbinit]

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/Hello/gcc-4.8.2/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

My question is to modify printers.py, write gdbinit, and then re-compile the process to test whether it has been applied as modified.
How can I print my modified TEST code at Linux Terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think that there was a problem with class StdStringPrinter at printers.py

I think you are fundamentally confused, and your problem has *nothing at all* to do with `printers.py`.

You didn't show us your GDB session, but it appears that you have tried to print some variable of type `std::string`, and when you did so, GDB produced this error:

> `RuntimeError: Cannot access memory at address 0x3b444e45203b290f`

What this error means is that GDB could not read value from memory location `0x3b444e45203b290f`. On an `x86_64` system, such a location indeed can not be readable, because that address does not have [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Canonical_form_addresses).

Conclusion: the pointer that you followed (likely a pointer to `std::string` in your program) does not actually point to `std::string`. "Fixing" the `printers.py` is not going to solve that problem.

This conclusion is corroborated by

> the process(c++ lang) running on Linux died,

Finally, the pointer that you gave GDB to print: `0x3b444e45203b290f` looks suspiciously like an `ASCII` string. Decoding it, we have: `\xf); END;`. So it's very likely that your program scribbled `); END;` over a location where the pointer was supposed to be, and that you have a buffer overflow of some sort.

P.S.

> My question is to modify printers.py, write gdbinit, and then re-compile the process to test whether it has been applied as modified.

This question also shows fundamental misunderstanding of how `printers.py` works. It has *nothing* to do with your program (it's loaded into GDB).

Recompiling *anything* (either your program or GDB) is *not* required. Simply restarting GDB should be all that's neccessary for it to pick up the new version of `printers.py` (not that that would fix anything).