# How to enable pretty printing for C++ in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, mingw

I am trying to enable pretty printing for C++ in Visual Studio Code using MinGW GDB python debugger.

I followed steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985414/how-to-enable-gdb-pretty-printing-for-c-stl-objects-in-eclipse-cdt) under the *"This is for MinGW users with Eclipse CDT"* heading, but when I try to start the debugger with `"externalConsole": true` I get the following logging output in the debug console:

```
1: (189) LaunchOptions{"name":"g++.exe - Build and debug active file","type":"cppdbg","request":"launch","program":"c:\\Users\\Ben Wilson\\Documents\\Scripts\\CodingChallenges\\movie.exe","args":[],"stopAtEntry":false,"cwd":"C:\\Users\\Ben Wilson\\Documents\\Scripts\\CodingChallenges","environment":[],"externalConsole":true,"MIMode":"gdb","miDebuggerPath":"C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb-python27.exe","setupCommands":[{"description":"Enable pretty-printing for gdb","text":"-enable-pretty-printing","ignoreFailures":true}],"preLaunchTask":"C/C++: g++.exe build active file","logging":{"engineLogging":true},"__configurationTarget":5,"__sessionId":"c62bc9d3-8c55-4dfb-b413-c91d22f3232e"}
1: (315) Starting: "C:\MinGW\bin\gdb-python27.exe" --interpreter=mi -x "C:\Users\Ben Wilson\Documents\Scripts\CodingChallenges\.gdbinit"
1: (328) DebuggerPid=11376
1: (391) "C:\MinGW\bin\gdb-python27.exe" exited with code -1073741515 (0xC0000135).
Starting: "C:\MinGW\bin\gdb-python27.exe" --interpreter=mi -x "C:\Users\Ben Wilson\Documents\Scripts\CodingChallenges\.gdbinit"
"C:\MinGW\bin\gdb-python27.exe" exited with code -1073741515 (0xC0000135).

1: (407) Send Event AD7MessageEvent
1: (408) <-logout
```

I tried setting `"externalConsole": false`, and I get this output to the debug console:

```
1: (123) LaunchOptions{"name":"g++.exe - Build and debug active file","type":"cppdbg","request":"launch","program":"c:\\Users\\Ben Wilson\\Documents\\Scripts\\CodingChallenges\\movie.exe","args":[],"stopAtEntry":false,"cwd":"C:\\Users\\Ben Wilson\\Documents\\Scripts\\CodingChallenges","environment":[],"externalConsole":false,"MIMode":"gdb","miDebuggerPath":"C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb-python27.exe","setupCommands":[{"description":"Enable pretty-printing for gdb","text":"-enable-pretty-printing","ignoreFailures":true}],"preLaunchTask":"C/C++: g++.exe build active file","logging":{"engineLogging":true},"__configurationTarget":5,"__sessionId":"cfbd8955-0807-495d-8bfa-e06052797523"}
1: (225) Wait for connection completion.
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb-python27.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "logging": { "engineLogging": true }
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Also, running the gdb-python27 executable separately doesnt seem to do anything (unsure if this is expected behaviour)

```
C:\Users\Ben Wilson\Documents\Scripts\CodingChallenges>C:\MinGW\bin\gdb-python27.exe

C:\Users\Ben Wilson\Documents\Scripts\CodingChallenges>
```

Has anyone experienced this before or know what to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

Fixed issue by:

1. Uninstalling mingw and installing mingw64 from this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download)
2. Modifying `miDebuggerPath` in `launch.json` and `command` and `cwd` in `tasks.json` to match new file locations
3. Adding new mingw64 bin location to PATH
4. Modifying `includePath` and `compilerPath` in `c_cpp_properties.json` to match new file locations

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered the same issue. My environments:

- Local/Remote: Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop/Server
- VSCode 1.60 + vscode_remote
- g++ with gdb 8

The setting `-enable-pretty-printing` is not working at all:

[image: Screenshot from 2021-09-04 20-04-51]

The following solution works for me:

1. check your gdb is supporting the 'pretty-print' which supplied by the python module of gdb:
   `readelf -d $(which gdb) | grep python`.
   if nothing is listed, unfortunately, you have to rebuild your gdb from the source.
2. Some requirements must be installed before rebuilding of gdb:
   `sudo apt install python libpython-dev # Python 2.7 and it's PythonLib will be installed in Ubuntu 18.04`
3. Download the latest gdb from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/) and unpack.
4. Perform the building and installation with the following configurations:

   ```
   ./configure --with-python
   make all -j16
   sudo make install -j16
   ```
5. Done!
   [image: Screenshot from 2021-09-04 20-01-05]

Ps.
If you are using conda, your Python environment maybe not correct for the GDB. Deactive your conda before debug:

```
conda deactivate
```

to make sure the correct version of Python is loaded by gdb.