# C++ gdb pretty printing in Ubuntu 18.04 visual studio code

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make pretty printing to work on Ubuntu 18.04 from visual studio code 1.64.2.

I tried to follow instructions initially from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203051/how-to-enable-pretty-printing-for-c-in-visual-studio-code) and then the answer by [Devymex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2841150/devymex) as detailed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203051/how-to-enable-pretty-printing-for-c-in-visual-studio-code/69132589#69132589).

Then further digging up revealed that the gdb pretty printing itself is not working as I tried to build, make, and run my code outside of VSCode. I had gcc 7.5 preinstalled on Ubuntu 18.04 and then I installed 11.2. But nothing worked.

The code I am trying to run

```
#include <string>    
#include <iostream>
std::string str = "hello world";
int main ()
{
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output I get while debugging with gdb

[image: Pretty Printing not working]

Additionally, I tried to check which pretty-printer is configured or set up by typing `info pretty-printer` from within (gdb). But it appears that the appropriate pretty printer is not configured.

[image: pretty printer info]

I tried reinstalling gcc 11.2 from the source by configuring with python using both python 2.7 and python 3.6.9 using the command `./configure --with-python` and `./configure --with-python3`. But nothing worked!

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606048/how-to-pretty-print-stl-containers-in-gdb/33223359#33223359). The gdb was not able to find the location where the python *printers.py* was located. The file was located under `/usr/share/gcc/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py`.

What I needed to do is create a .gdbinit file on my home directory including the following lines of code

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/gcc/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

Next source the file with `source .gdbinit` and then try again the `info pretty-print`. All the alternate options are now available. Subsequently, gdb debugging and vscode was able to show the contents of the C++ STL containers.