# How can I use pretty-printing for gdb like lldb on vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, pretty-print

When I use vscode, the pretty-printer for gdb seems quite different from lldb.
The lldb on MacOs will show some field details and the size of containers directly which will be helpful when I debug.

gdb pretty-print on linux
[image: gdb pretty-print on linux]

lldb on MacOS
[image: lldb on MacOS]

So how can I achieve a similar effect with gdb on linux?

I set my gdb pretty-printer by following
[How to enable gdb pretty printing for C++ STL objects in Eclipse CDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5713387/15352371)

And I set my launch.json on Vscode like this

```
"configurations": [
{
    "name": "C++ Launch",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/a.out",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/include/",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "setupCommands": [
        { 
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "description": "enable pretty printing", 
            "ignoreFailures": true 
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the same behaviour on Ubuntu 23.04 with MS VS Code 1.83.1 installed from Ubuntu Snap Store (latest/stable) and vscode-cpptools extension v1.17.5 (latest stable).

[image]

There is a bug report filed against the `vscode-cpptools` extension at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/8485 from Dec 3, 2021 which is still open (October 2023).