# suggestion for good IDE for C/C++ with debugging features

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, stl, gdb

I am currently using Eclipse for C/C++ programming. Though i am accustomed to using eclipse for Java, i cannot figure out a good workflow for using Eclipse for C/C++

What i find lacking is a good debugging support. STL structures (vector, map) are not displayed in debug view as they are equivalently displayed in Java. They are displayed in a very obscure manner which is hard to interpret.

Upon googling i found 
[Better variable exploring when debugging C++ code with Eclipse/CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651862/better-variable-exploring-when-debugging-c-code-with-eclipse-cdt)
but i find the method not robust. It cannot display STL structures with objects (strings too) in them. Extending the .gdbinit file to support those will be an entire new project for me (as i am a new programmer)

Is there some other IDE good for C/C++ programming and debugging. Or is there something i am missing because certainly for such a industry standard language there must be some good 
support out there.

EDIT: I am on a Win or *nix

Answer (score 2):

I use visual studio express on Windows. It is free with alot of debugging functions.

```
 1. Microsoft Visual Studio Express C/C++ (Best for Windows)
 2. Code Blocks (Best of *nix)
 3. Eclipse for C/C++
 4. Netbeans
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Visual Studio has the best debugger, no problems displaying STL classes.

Comment: @john yep the best so far I have used in any C/C++ or C# compiler. Kudos to MS

Answer (score 1):

On Linux I would prefer to use [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

You can also look for [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/)

> **GNU DEBUGGER**
>
> The C and C++ editor is well integrated with the multi-session GNU gdb
>   debugger. You can set variable, exception, system call, line, and
>   function breakpoints and view them in the Breakpoints window. Inspect
>   the call stack and local variables, create watches, and view threads.
>   You can evaluate a selected expression by moving the cursor over it
>   and viewing the tooltip. The Disassembler window displays the assembly
>   instructions for the current source file.

Comment: as far as i have heard.. code::blocks has the same problems with debugging that i mentioned in my question

Comment: @Archit:- You may try with Net Beans also!!!

Comment: does it have the debugging support better than eclipse?

Comment: @Archit:- I am not sure that if it is better or not. But I am pretty sure that the Debugger is excellent in Net Beans!!! :)

Comment: what i meant to ask was does it solve the problem that i mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Archit:- Yes for sure!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38256/discussion-between-archit-and-rahul-tripathi)

Answer (score 0):

If your on a mac xcode is pretty good.

Comment: I dont have a mac. mayb you could suggest a win/linux alternative

Comment: xcode is not pretty good

Answer (score 0):

Embarcadero C++ Builder, also available as part of RAD Studio, is quite good, and has been undergoing significant development over the past couple of years.

It can be used to develop Win32 apps, Win64 apps, Mac OS X apps, as well as iOS and Android apps (the mobile OS's are only in the RAD Studio in the Delphi language for now, but C++ support is expected by the end of the year)

It has excellent debugging support as well.  The IDE runs only on Windows, but does work quite well in a Virtual Machine running Windows inside a Mac, with either VMWare or Parallels.  It does require a Mac, running Xcode, to compile Mac OS X or iOS applications -- that can be a separate computer, or the "Mother Ship" if you are running Windows in a Virtual Machine on the Mac.