# Inspecting contents of std::vector in Eclipse CDT debugger

Tags: c++, eclipse, std

I'm using Eclipse with the CDT plugin to develop in C++. I'm also using std library to create vectors and I am having an issue while debugging:  Eclipse does not allow me to view the content of the vectors.

Is there any way to be able to debug it properly?

Comment: The chances that there are errors in `std::vector` are quite slim indeed, compared to the probability that the error is in your *use* of it. Are you really sure you need this? If you do, you'd need a debug version of the C++ standard library installed, and link against that... no idea how to do that in Eclipse, though. I never debugged the standard library in fourteen years of doing professional C++ maintenance. (Found two bugs in Boost and one in the IBM AIX debugger, though, so never say never. ;-) )

Comment: Whatever problems you have, if any, the chances they are in the standard library are slim to none. The problems are probably how you use these classes, or what you try to store in the containers.

Comment: I may explained myself wrongly. I don't want to check how is the class vector made, I want to see what is inside a vector (my classes).

Comment: Still can't help with Eclipse CDT as I don't use it, but you *should* be able to inspect any object's contents. For `std::vector`, there's probably an element `data` or somesuch inside the vector object, holding the individual elements of the vector... bowing out of this and leaving the field to people actually using Eclipse CDT.

Comment: There is not an easy way to check a std::vector, that's why I'm asking this.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651862/better-variable-exploring-when-debugging-c-code-with-eclipse-cdt).

Answer (score 21):

Debugging STL containers in Eclipse is not quite straightforward. Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3651862/2429404) and the answers explaining the reasons for this. The simplest way without fiddling with the GDB for me is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158450/2429404), which can be summarized as follows:

Expand your vector in the variable view, you should find a nested variable `_M_start`. Right-click, choose "Display As Array..." and enter the desired range. The elements should then show up nested under `_M_start`.

Comment: is this a complete answer? If the link goes down will it still be valid?

Comment: That is why I summarized the answer I linked to in the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: It works indeed, but wow, I wish Eclipse CDT could fix this in the future and make it straightforward.

Comment: Using "Display As Array" requires you to write down the number of elements you want to view. No need to say way what happens if you write down more than the vector actually contains. :D