# How does one debug std::stack, std::deque, std::list etc. in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, list, debugging, stack

**IMPONRATNT:** I'm using an old version of gcc (**32bit MinGW 4.8.1**) and Eclipse (**Kepler Service Release 2, Build id: 20140224-0627**). Upgrading any of the tools I'm using is **not allowed**.

---

I haven't used Eclipse in a very long time (a couple of years). I simply want to check the contents (for example each integer in a `std::stack<int>`, each string in a `std::deque<std::string>` etc.). Instead I get this iterator stuff:

[image]

I tried using the **Expressions** view but I don't know how much code one can insert there. Not to mention that you can go "infinitely" deep by following the `_M_next` and `_M_prev` without achieving a thing.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246065/inspecting-contents-of-stdvector-in-eclipse-cdt-debugger

Comment: Also, updating your gcc and gdb should help, unless eclipse is bad. Modern gcc prints the contents of C++ containers just fine.

Comment: I'm not allowed to update anything. Eclipse is also old (will add this in the question since I forgot and it's an important piece of info). All the tools I'm using are set in stone since it's a project for a customer of the company I'm working for.